# How can I tell kmalloc to use big (>2M) pages?

Tags: memory, pager, opensuse, kmalloc

I am writing a device driver to allocate a large buffer for DMA.  My system is using (or so I believe) 4k pages, and I want it to use larger pages, i.e. at least 2M pages.

How can I:

- enable large pages in the system (or check if they're enabled)?
- specify that the current `kmalloc` should use large pages?

Comment: I'm not sure precisely how to allocate large pages, so I can't answer the question directly, but do note that often large pages simply aren't available due to memory fragmentation. If your device (or IOMMU) supports scatter-gather DMA, it's better to use that instead of a single giant buffer; otherwise, you'll need to reserve your memory early in the boot process, when there are still large contiguous chunks of free physical memory.